# Google Line Chart - Refresh database automatically

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, google-visualization, partial-page-refresh

I'm working on an interface which display data retrieved from my database thanks to a Google Line Chart. However, new data is stored in my database every 10 seconds and I can not refresh the chart automatically.

I need something really basic and I've already looked on the internet. I read something about Javascript/AJAX/JQuery ... but I'm more comfortable with Hardware :D

Here's my files
EDIT : Chart_get and the main file have been modified according to @Michel answer.

**fetch.php - Fetch the data and echo**

```
<?php // Connection and Request stuff

  $host = blablabla
  (...)
  $req = $bdd->query('SELECT id, battery FROM Station');

  while ($data = $req->fetch()){
      $id = addslashes($data['id']);
      $charge_batt = intval($data['charge_batt']);
      $result .= "['".$id."' , ".$charge_batt."],";
  }

  $result = substr($result, 0, -1); // Erase the last ","
  echo $result;

?>
```

Output :

```
['1' , 90],['2' , 89],['3' , 80],['4' , 100],['5' , 90],['6' , 50],['7' , 67]
```

**chart_get.php - Initialize the chart and draw it with the "echo $result" data**

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([    
<?php   
        echo ("['Date', 'Battery'],");
        include('fetch.php');
?>    
        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'Battery health',
          animation:{
              duration: 1000,
              easing: 'out',
          },
          curveType: 'function'
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }      
    </script>


    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

To refresh the "chart_div" I've tried :

**main.html - jQuery script with load function**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="fr" lang="fr">
    <head>

            <title>Project - Chart</title>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />

        <script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                // first load it once, so it display's the chart 
                $('#tableHolder').load('chart_get.php');
                // then execute the interval
                setInterval(function(){$('#tableHolder').load('chart_get.php');}, 5000);
                });
    </script>

    </head>

    <body>

        <p>Hello</p>
        <div id="tableHolder"> </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

But the chart is not displayed at all.
I have absolutely no idea what I'm doing wrong. I am reading in a fast way some tutorials about javascript but if you know how to resolve my issue it would be great to help me :)
**Thanks !**

Comment: What does the console say? Does it give any errors?

Comment: @Michel Hi ! The fetch.php returns correctly my array. The chart_get.php displays correctly the line graph. The main.html doesn't give me any error, yet the page doesn't display the graph called in tableHolder. (It only displays "Hello".

Comment: Edit : My chart_get itself contains some <!DOCTYPE><html><head><meta> and <div> stuff. It may be in conflict with the main.html ? Should I let only the <script> in chart_get.php ?

Comment: This setup isn't going to work, because if you try to load the Visualization API multiple times, it will only load and call it's callback the first time.  Is it necessary in your application to load your chart script separate from the main page?

Comment: @asgallant I have no constraint in the way my chart script is used :) I just want the chart to be refreshed. Must I place the google.load("visualization") in the main page and refresh the callback ? I'll try to :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Solution from OP.*

**I've found the answer!**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="fr" lang="fr">
    <head>

            <title>Projet GreenFeed - Station de recharge a energie positive</title>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />


        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

        // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
        google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});

        // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

        function drawChart() {

//AJAX Call is compulsory !

        var jsonData = $.ajax({
          url: "chart_fetch.php",
          dataType:"json",
          async: false
          }).responseText;

          // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
          var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

          var options = {
               title: 'Battery',
              is3D: 'true',
              width: 800,
              height: 600
            };
          // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
          // Do not forget to check your div ID
          var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
          chart.draw(data, options);
        }
        </script>


        <script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

                $(document).ready(function(){
                    // First load the chart once 
                    drawChart();
                    // Set interval to call the drawChart again
                    setInterval(drawChart, 5000);
                    });
        </script>

    </head>

    <body>

        <div id="chart_div"> </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First get rid of the `<!DOCTYPE>`, `<html>`, `<head>`, `<meta>`, `<title>` tags in chart_get.php.
The data in `chart_get.php` is the same data you would have in `<div id="tableHolder"></div>` if you didn't wanted it to refresh.

Second, rewrite your script in `main.html` to this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        // first load it once, so it display's the chart 
        // (otherwise you have to wait 5 seconds)
        $('#tableHolder').load('chart_get.php');
        // then execute the interval
        setInterval(function(){$('#tableHolder').load('chart_get.php');}, 5000);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Ok Michel I've changed my files according to your answer. Yet the chart doesn't appear even with the first $('#tableHolder').load('chart_get.php'); load.
Asgallant says the google.load("visualization") should not be placed in the chart_get.php script. I've tried to place it in the main script but that's not working ^^ (I'm experimenting ^^)

Comment: I've noticed that my <p>Hello</p> in the main.html disappears after 5seconds

Comment: Have you tried to put the javascript of `chart_get.php` inside the `setInterval` in the `main.html`? And changing the output of the javascript to `tableHolder` instead of `chart_div`?

Comment: Nop doesn't work :'( I'm trying something completely different. The 'main.hmtl' contains both the javascript of 'chart_get.php' and the 'setInterval' which call the 'drawChart' function ! Yet, I'm will need some AJAX to fetch the data dynamically won't I ? Ok let's go ... :p

Comment: UPDATE : OK I've found the way to do it :) I've updated my question with the answer. In a nutshell : the both scripts are in the main.html but the drawChart() function execute an AJAX call to the chart_fetch.php so that data are refreshed. Then, the setIntervall calls the drawChart() function :)

Comment: Seems like you used a json in your answer.. do you have the example json?

Comment: @AlexvanEs I did not used JSON. the chart_get.php is a file with JavaScript content, as seen in the question of the OP.